# PoolablePreparedStatement memory leak

Tags: java, spring

I have a program which executes a lot of update statements on a db.
The program gets slower everytime an object (multiple inserts and updates per object) is imported into database. At first it takes just a couple of ms per object and in the end it's about 2 or 3 seconds.

I can't paste the code because I don't know exactly what could be causing this.

I analysed the heap dump and it says there are a lot of instances of the class PoolablePreparedStatement.

[image]

> 155.418 instances of "org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolablePreparedStatement", loaded by
>   "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x5c0e60e88" occupy 1.831.282.544
>   (77,16%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of
>   "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]", loaded by ""
>
> Keywords java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolablePreparedStatement
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x5c0e60e88

A lot of methods use the annotation

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

Can someone explain this behaviour or give me a hint?

Comment: What is your spring version and why are you not using Hikari?

Comment: It is spring 4.1.1. I don't know Hikari. How does it help? It is legacy code I have to optimise

Comment: There is a closeable resource that does not close. Or that you have a loop somewhere without an exit. You don't need Hikari. That plugin is useful because it manages the db connection pool for you.

Comment: DBCP2 is a conection pool but as mentioned you might want to try HikariCP as an alternative and possible better implementation. That being said please post some code that is doing the updates/inserts. Is it a batch process that does everything in one large transaction? Is JPA involved etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: There was a statement that had a parameter included into the query string. I extracted it and put it where the others are and now it stays fast.

```
template.update("UPDATE table SET x = ?, y = ?, z = '" + somethingUnique + "' WHERE id = ? ", /*the args...*/);
```

Change to

```
template.update("UPDATE table SET x = ?, y = ?, z = ? WHERE id = ? ", /*the args...*/);
```

It seems there were so many statements saved in the map that the program could slower and slower with each iteration